# Can we sort by outV or inV in gremlin?

Tags: java, pagination, gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

How to sort by `inV()` or `outE()` from the edge?

I need to get the roles that are assigned to the `user`.

Users can have multiple roles.

```
g.addV('project').as('p').
.addV('user').property(T.id, 'u1').as('u1')
.addV('user').property(T.id, 'u2').as('u2')
.addE('role').from('p').to('u1').property('role', 'role1')
.addE('role').from('p').to('u1').property('role', 'role2')
.addE('role').from('p').to('u1').property('role', 'role3')
.addE('role').from('p').to('u2').property('role', 'role1')
```

In, the above graph, the project has 2 users and user `u1` has 3 roles and `u2` has 1 role.

How to retrieve all edges/roles with `range` but by the user.

```
g.V('p').outE().range(1, 2).inV().elementMap()
```

The above query returns few edges of the user, not all edges/roles belong to the user.

How to query it?

[image: relationship]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would make sure that you're not confusing labels and IDs when it comes to how you are defining user vertices.  In the generated graph query that you provide, the `addV()` step is setting the label for the vertices that you want to add.  So instead of creating to `user` vertices, you are creating two vertices with labels of `u1` and `u2`.  Instead, you would want to do something like:

```
g.addV('project').property(id,'p1').as('p')
.addV('user').property(id,'u1').as('u1')
.addV('user').property(id,'u2').as('u2')
.addE('role').from('p').to('u1').property('role', 'role1')
.addE('role').from('p').to('u1').property('role', 'role2')
.addE('role').from('p').to('u1').property('role', 'role3')
.addE('role').from('p').to('u2').property('role', 'role1')
```

To fetch a mapping of user to role from a given project, you would start from the selected project vertex (`p1`, in this case) and then traverse along the graph until you reached the user vertices.  You would use `as()` labels along the way to denote portions of the traversal that you want to output later.  Using a `select()` step, you can then build the output that you desire:

```
g.V('p1').outE('role').as('r').
   inV().as('u').
   select('u','r').
       by(id()).
       by('role')
```

This will provide the following output:

```
[{'u': 'u1', 'r': 'role1'},
 {'u': 'u1', 'r': 'role2'},
 {'u': 'u1', 'r': 'role3'},
 {'u': 'u2', 'r': 'role1'}]
```

Comment: need to use `by(elementMap())` instead of `by('role')`

Answer (score 0):

With `range` for the pagination.

```
g.V(project_id).as('p')
.outE('role').inV().dedup().as('user').range(0,2)
.inE('role').as("r").outV().where(eq("p")).select("r").elementMap()
```